# PHP- Send mail with SMTP authentication without mail()

Tags: php, email, authentication, smtp

I am working on a website which is hosted on a server that has the function "mail()" disabled for security reasons.

I would like to know if there is another way around to bypass this and send an email with SMTP authentication ?

I don't own the server and I can't install any add-ons or plugins. There isn't PEAR nor Swift nor PHPMailer on that server.

How should I do?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Swift, PHPMailer can both be 'installed' by you - they just need to be copied there, where your code has access to it. PEAR_Mail probably works the same way.

Comment: The website is hosted on a shared server which I don't have access to (no SSH) so it is not possible for me to copy anything on it.

Comment: then how do you put your site there?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise you didn't need to install them into some folders with special permission or something. And I just needed to copy the scripts. Sorry about that !
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to `"install"` PHPMailer. Just upload the script in your server and include it in your script.

I believe if you could use `mail()` function you can upload files to the server.

If you cannot, then you can't do nothing.